# NoClassDefFoundError: Mockito Bytebuddy

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, mockito

I recently added Mockito to a maven project on eclipse, by adding the external jar "mockito-core-2.0.53-beta.jar", and upon attempting to create my first mock object (Line two in the function)

[image]

And upon running it, the console prints out the first line, then throws this error:

[image]

It seems like previously there was a similar issue, but it was supposedly fixed internally. https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/issues/99

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You simply forgot to add the dependencies to your project which are according to the pom file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
  <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.16</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
  <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

In other words you need to add `byte-buddy 1.3.16` and `objenesis 2.1` to your project too.

More details [here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.mockito%7Cmockito-core%7C2.0.53-beta%7Cjar)

Comment: This is not working in 2022. I'm experiencing this issue and any of the solutions worked for me. Using the last version of these dependencies, I got a "Dependency not found" in intelliJ.

Answer (score 2):

There is a post that explain the problem pretty well, you can find it here:

https://solidsoft.wordpress.com/2012/09/11/beyond-the-mockito-refcard-part-3-mockito-core-vs-mockito-all-in-mavengradle-based-projects/

If you are not using gradle or maven and you are just using mockit-core you should add these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
  <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.9</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
  <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead adding

> mockito-core

better option will to add

> mockito-all

Refer to this link https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all/2.0.2-beta

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-core-vs-mockito-all

"As we explored above, mockito-core is the main artifact of Mockito. Newer versions don't release mockito-all anymore. Henceforth, we should only use mockito-core."

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

This indicates that in your .jar (org.mockito), you don't have that class.
This usually occurs when you have more than one .jar (with a different version) in your classpath. You could check that.